# Babel error: Module not found: Can't resolve '<local_structure>/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' after new component

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

Tree Output from the `src` directory:

```
src/
├── App.css
├── App.js
├── App.test.js
├── components
│   └── layout
│       ├── About.js
│       ├── Header.js
│       ├── Hero.js
│       ├── References.js
│       └── Resume.js
├── img
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── HMR.jpeg
│   ├── speaking.jpeg
│   ├── favicon.png
│   ├── nepal-bg.jpeg
│   └── testimonials-bg.jpeg
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── reportWebVitals.js
└── setupTests.js
```

`References.js`

```
const References = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>These are my refs</p>    
        </div>
    )
}

export default References
```

`App.js`

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/layout/Header'
import Hero from './components/layout/Hero'
import About from './components/layout/About'
import Resume from './components/layout/Resume'
import References from './components/layout/References'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Container'>
      <Header />
      <Hero />
      <About />
      <Resume />
      <References />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The site works fine until I add the `References.js` file into my `App.js` file.  I have removed `node_modules` and reinstalled.  I have installed the suggested npm packages.  I can't figure out what is introducing the breaking change every time I try to add the component.

Comment: try to run `npm install` and then `npm start` your application again.

Comment: That fixed it. Can't believe that was all it was since I uninstalled and re-installed dependencies multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the `node_modules`, stopping the server, running `npm i` and restarting the server with `npm start` fixed the issue.